# Mapping object type property to varbinary(MAX) in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, ef-fluent-api

I have a situation where I have a type with a property of type `object`, eg.

```
public class MyType
{
   public virtual object MyProp{get; get;}
}
```

This type will have to be:

1. Saved using `Entity Framework` to a database, as a `byte[]` (I have figured the serialization logic)
2. Transmitted through WCF (I will use the `KnownType` attribute)

**How do I map my `object` property ensuring that it is converted it to a byte array for storage?**

N.B: The `object` property will be a value type(non-complex)

I thought of creating a separate type for saving to the database e.g:

```
public class MyTypeEntity
{
   public virtual byte[] MyProp{get; get;}
}
```

**How do I convert/translate between the types while still able to define the relationship mappings?**

**Does this involve some sort of interception on saving?**

The best solution I could think of without breaking my back is simply storing the serialized data in the DB.

If there was some form of `property covariance` in C#, maybe this would've worked easier. As far as I know, it does not exist.
If there is an elegant alternative that I can use, I would appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would recommend keeping a `byte[]` field on your entity; your class should really mimic the database structure as closely as possible. One way I've done something similar to this in the past is to create a separate class file (remember, your entities are `partial`) and add a `NotMapped` property to the second file. You can make the getter and setter do the conversion from `object` to `byte[]` and in your code, just always interact with the `object` property that EF will ignore. It's pretty painless, and EF will still track the `varbinary` field to the `byte[]` that you don't directly access.

Comment: Briliant idea! definitely painless. Had no idea I could use partials (EF newbie) .Thanks @DrewJordan

Comment: You could include it in the first file if you wanted... I like to keep the database model by itself though.

Comment: Will see what will be more acceptable with the team, otherwise I share the same sentiment. Do I have to place any attribute decorations to ensure it is not mapped? Or just not mapping it will suffice?

Comment: Yes, the attribute is `NotMapped`, on your new property.

Comment: Got it. Had missed that one. Thanks!